# Do SQL Select Statements need to be parameterized in asp?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, asp-classic

I have some SQL select statements listed below. Is there any reason to parameterize such queries? There are some written in asp and some in asp.net.

asp.net using sqldatasource control:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM HEADLINES  WHERE visible = 'Yes' AND FIN = 'Yes' ORDER BY DATE DESC></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

One of the queries in asp classic using the ADO recordset object:

```
Set Season = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Season.ActiveConnection = INTERNET_STRING
Season.Source = "SELECT *  FROM SEASON  WHERE SHOW_INDIC = Season_var
```

These queries don't accept user input but they are on the asp/aspx pages rather than the code behind, should I be worried about potential SQL injection or any other vulnerabilites? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to worry about a constant SQL string in terms of SQL injection.

Comment: It's not clear from your code what you are doing is `"SELECT *  FROM SEASON  WHERE SHOW_INDIC = Season_var` meant to be `"SELECT *  FROM SEASON  WHERE SHOW_INDIC = Season_var"` or `"SELECT *  FROM SEASON  WHERE SHOW_INDIC = " & Season_var`? If it's the later then the answer depends on where the `Season_var` comes from.

Comment: The Season_var is a string variable which is pulled from the url when the page loads in a browser. ie. www.url.com?season='abc'

Comment: Still doesn't answer my question, are you concatenating that value onto your sql string? If yes then you are open to SQL injection and should look at parametrising your query.

Comment: Yes I am concatenating that onto my query, I am going to fix that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameterizing queries will eliminate SQL-injections. If you have variables in your query, your query is vulnerable. For more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx

However, your first query is static, it has no variables. There is no reason for a static query to parameterize.

Your second query has variables, and therefor it should be parameterized.

Comment: It looks like it isn't static after all.